# what is the difference between onClick and mouseClick?

Tags: java, events, mouse

wondering what is the major difference between these two: onClick and mouseClick..

Comment: Are you asking about Java, or Javascript?

Comment: Java, I am just confused between these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about Java, the difference is right there in the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) for MouseEvent:

> Mouse Events
>
> ```
> * a mouse button is pressed
> * a mouse button is released
> * a mouse button is clicked (pressed and released)
> * the mouse cursor enters the unobscured part of component's geometry
> * the mouse cursor exits the unobscured part of component's geometry
> ```

If you're talking about JavaScript, I'm going to assume that it's the difference between old style and new style [event handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). But I've only ever used onClick, so can't give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are confusing Java with Javascript. There is not onClick() method on Java APIs.