# What is the difference between a click and mouseclick?

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the difference between a click and mouseclick?

Comment: Should this question be considered a language neutral winforms question? It also applies to [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722029/what-is-the-difference-between-onclick-and-mouseclick), AutoHotkey ([Click](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm) & [MouseClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm)), and [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852410/what-is-the-difference-between-a-click-and-mouseclick), just to name a few.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to WinForm Control events, from the MSDN documentation for [Control.Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx):

> The Click event passes an EventArgs to its event handler, so it only indicates that a click has occurred. If you need more specific mouse information (button, number of clicks, wheel rotation, or location), use the MouseClick event. However, the MouseClick event will not be raised if the click is caused by action other than that of the mouse, such as pressing the ENTER key.

Comment: Will the Click event be raised if the click is caused by action other than that of the mouse such as pressing the ENTER key?

Comment: @jj_ - Yes, it does.

Answer (score 17):

A click can be caused by not only a mouse click, but also some events like a pressed key, etc. For more information, see *[Control.Click Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx)*.