# Click, DoubleClick vs MouseClick and MouseDoubleClick events

Tags: winforms, notifyicon

I just found out that there are 4 similarly names events for `NotifyIcon` named `Click`, `DoubleClick`, `MouseClick` and `MouseDoubleClick`. The description text for them says

> Occurs when the component is (double-)clicked [with mouse].

But what else can you click elements with except mouse?

I tried clicking it with mouse and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after some tricky selection stuff with arrow keys and tabbing. Clicking with mouse fires both events, but pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> only fires the `Click` event.

What other differences are between these two pairs of events?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a click and mouseclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852410/what-is-the-difference-between-a-click-and-mouseclick)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to WinForm Control events, from the MSDN documentation for [Control.Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx):

> A click can be caused by not only a mouse click, but also some events
>   like a pressed key, etc.
>
> The Click event passes an EventArgs to its event handler, so it only indicates that a click has occurred. If you need more specific mouse information (button, number of clicks, wheel rotation, or location), use the MouseClick event. However, the MouseClick event will not be raised if the click is caused by action other than that of the mouse, such as pressing the ENTER key.

- **Click Event**

The Click event passes an EventArgs to its event handler, so it only indicates that a click has occurred. If you need more specific mouse information (button, number of clicks, wheel rotation, or location), use the MouseClick event. However, the MouseClick event will not be raised if the click is caused by action other than that of the mouse, such as pressing the ENTER key.

- **Mouse Click Event**

Depressing a mouse button when the cursor is over a control typically raises the following series of events from the control:

1. MouseDown event.
2. Click event.
3. MouseClick event.
4. MouseUp event.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852410/what-is-the-difference-between-a-click-and-mouseclick/3852428#3852428)

Comment: Right, `MouseEventArgs`. Useful indeed.